# How do I display text in view with respect to a boolean variable in the $scope in angularjs?

Tags: binding, angularjs

Suppose I have a variable in the $scope:

> $scope.smsProfile.Active

which can be true or false and I would like to display a text on the screen with respect to it's value. For example if it is true display "Profile active" and if it is false display "Profile not active". How can I do that?

I tried like this:

```
{{true:'Profile active', false:'Profile not active'}[$scope.smsProfile.Active]}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-hide and/or ng-show directive:

```
<span ng-show="smsProfile.Active">Profile active</span>
<span ng-hide="smsProfile.Active">Profile not active</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a method in controller:

```
$scope.smsProfile= {
        Active: true,
        statusText: function () {
            return $scope.foo.Active ? 'active' : 'not active';
        }
    }
```

Then output the method in an expression or `ng-bind`

```
<span>Profile is {{smsProfile.statusText()}}</span>
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/zpfq4/

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it without writing another function?

Comment: possibly... but expression guide docs state following: **No Control Flow Statements**

You cannot write a control flow statement in an expression. The reason behind this is core to the Angular philosophy that application logic should be in controllers, not in the view. If you need a conditional, loop, or to throw from a view expression, delegate to a JavaScript method instead.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: one other alternative might be use `ng-switch`

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a bit old, I wanted to reference this for anybody that ends up here:

[How do I display text in view with respect to a boolean variable in the $scope in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183673/how-do-i-display-text-in-view-with-respect-to-a-boolean-variable-in-the-scope-i)

Another example, following the logic from the above post using ternary operators is below. This example is based on a checkbox list with a toggle button to select all or none. If all are selected (the length is the same), then the option text will change to *Select None*.

```
{{ (selected.length === options.length) ? 'Select None' : 'Select All'}}
```

Following that logic, the above could also be written like so:

```
{{ (selected.length !== options.length) ? 'Select All' : 'Select None'}}
```

For more information on this, see the below article from Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator